# Are there any products that create a SourceSafe to TFS bridge? (SourceSafe facade)

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe

We have a ton of code written in [Dexterity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexterity_programming_language), whose only Source Control integration option is SourceSafe. Are there any products out there that could act as a bridge so that Dexterity would believe it was talking to a SourceSafe server, but all the commands were actually translated to TFS (2010) actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - that's exactly what the TFS MSSCCI Provider ([2010 Beta 2 version](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/f959ea32-5ac3-424a-a709-5001a158ebe8)) does.

Dexterity doesn't appear in the list of supported apps so it's probably not very well tested, if at all.  On the bright side, [Michal](http://blogs.msdn.com/michalma/) is very receptive to bug reports; hopefully he'd be able to fix any issues you encounter before the final 2010 power tools are released.

Comment: Awesome, thanks..will test it out and get in touch with Michal. Fingers crossed!